# Oracle BD триггеры

Tags: база-данных, oracle

У меня почему-то не срабатывают триггеры, хотя написаны они правильно, стоит enabled. Просто срабатывает исключение no data found и столбцы устанавливаются в значение null.

```
CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP"  

   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."GROUP_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0,  

    "C_RETAIL" NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  

    "MARKUP" NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") 

  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS  

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_CHK1" CHECK (markup >= 0 AND markup <= 1 

) ENABLE 

   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE  

  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255  

 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS" ; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES"  

AFTER UPDATE OF MARKUP ON product_group 

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

  -- Обновляем розничные цены в таблице "Товары" для соответствующей группы 

  UPDATE product 

  SET retail_price = entry_price * (1 + :NEW.markup) 

  WHERE group_id = :NEW.id; 

   -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" ENABLE; 

 

 

  CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT"  

   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."PRODUCT_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "GROUP_ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "ENTRY_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  

    "RETAIL_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  

    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") 

  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS  

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("GROUP_ID") 

      REFERENCES "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" ("ID") ENABLE 

   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE  

  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255  

 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS" ; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE"  

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product 

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

  DECLARE 

    v_markup product_group.markup%TYPE; 

    -- Получаем наценку на группу товара 

  BEGIN 

    SELECT markup 

    INTO v_markup 

    FROM product_group 

    WHERE id = :NEW.group_id; 

 

    -- Вычисляем розничную цену 

    :NEW.retail_price := :NEW.entry_price * (1 + v_markup); 

  EXCEPTION 

    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 

      -- Eсли группа товара не найдена 

      :NEW.retail_price := NULL; 

  END; 

   -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" ENABLE; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT"  

AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON product 

FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 

  v_group_id NUMBER; 

BEGIN 

  -- Получаем идентификатор группы товаров для текущего товара 

  SELECT group_id INTO v_group_id 

  FROM product 

  WHERE id = :NEW.id; 

 

  -- Обновляем количество товаров в группе 

  UPDATE product_group 

  SET count = ( 

    SELECT count 

    FROM product 

    WHERE group_id = v_group_id 

  ); 

 

  -- Обновляем сводную стоимость группы 

  UPDATE product_group 

  SET c_retail = ( 

    SELECT (entry_price * count) 

    FROM product 

    WHERE group_id = v_group_id 

  ); 

 

  -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END ; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT" ENABLE; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_C_RETAIL_TRIGGER"  

AFTER UPDATE ON product FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

  -- Пересчитываем сводную стоимость для соответствующей группы 

  UPDATE product_group pg 

  SET c_retail = ( 

    SELECT (p.retail_price * p.count) 

    FROM product p 

    WHERE p.group_id = pg.id 

  ) 

  WHERE id = :NEW.group_id; 

   -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_C_RETAIL_TRIGGER" ENABLE;
```

Comment: Исключение наверное не просто так срабатывает... его надо обрабатывать. Самоисключение говорит, что в выборке пришло 0 строк. Проверяйте, какие значения передаете, порядок выполнения запросов. Добавьте в скрипты dbms_output отладочную информацию и все станет ясно